# Salesforce DX - Scratch org definition file - Failed to deploy settings with territory2 activated

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I'm trying to create a scratch org using the scratch org definition file below:

```
{
  "orgName": "Demo Company",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": [
    "Communities",
    "ServiceCloud",
    "Knowledge",
    "WavePlatform",
    "MultiCurrency",
    "Entitlements",
    "LiveAgent",
    "FieldService",
    "AuthorApex",
    "DebugApex",
    "Sites",
    "MarketingUser",
    "DefaultWorkflowUser",
    "AnalyticsAdminPerms"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true,
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
      "translation": true,
      "chatterEnabled": true,
      "enhancedEmailEnabled": true
    },
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableAccountTeams": true
    },
    "forecastingSettings": {
      "enableForecasts": true
    },
    "quoteSettings": {
      "enableQuote": true
    },
    "liveAgentSettings": {
      "enableLiveAgent": true
    },
    "territory2Settings": {
      "enableTerritoryManagement2": true
    }
  }
}
```

The territory2 activation settings is based on the following documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/47/Territory2/scratch-def/developer

The only error raised by sfdx is:

> Failed to deploy settings to scratch org.

Any idea why?